# How to bind Tika python with Tesseract OCR?

Tags: python, apache, ocr, tesseract, apache-tika

When i'm calling this in terminal it works perfectly!

`tesseract 1.jpg outPutFileHere -l fra`

But i'm trying to make it works with tika

```
import tika
import sys
from tika import parser
from tika import detector
tikedDocument = parser.from_file(TextImage)
```

with the same text image i have no results with tika :(

Have you an idea on what's going on?

Thank You

Comment: Can you format your code?

Comment: Did you follow https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaOCR ?

Comment: Yup! i'have tested to follow apache tika short tutorial, they just say to install tesseract and then tika and... that's all! i recode tesseract function by calling it by subprocess and getting returns values by files etc... But that's not what i wanted first! Tika should do it !

Comment: @john doe   Yup! just do a script python using tika for exemple call if from subprocess you can catch errors and warnings by stdout and use tesseract when tika can't get data out of pdf.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide header called "X-Tika-OCRLanguage" for example:

```
headers = {
    "X-Tika-OCRLanguage": "eng+nor"
}
parsed = parser.from_file(path, headers=headers)
```